# Columns to arrays with perl

Tags: perl

Need put columns to arrays. Currently have the next working code:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my @aa;
my @ab;
my @ac;

while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my($x,$y,$z) = split /\s*:\s*/;
        push(@aa,$x);
        push(@ab,$y);
        push(@ac,$z);
}
say Dumper \@aa, \@ab, \@ac;

__DATA__
col1a : col1b : col1c
col2a : col2b : col2c
col3a : col3b : col3c
```

Exists some more compact, elegant way to do the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @t = split /\s*:\s*/;
        push(@aa, shift @t);
        push(@ab, shift @t);
        push(@ac, shift @t);
}
say Dumper \@aa, \@ab, \@ac;
```

or you can use 2d array,

```
my @arr;
while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @t = split /\s*:\s*/;
        push @{$arr[$_]}, $t[$_] for 0 .. $#t;
}
say Dumper \@arr;
```

Comment: The 2D array is great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can use a variable to point to the end of the arrays:

```
my $i = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        ($aa[$i], $ab[$i], $ac[$i++]) = split /\s*:\s*/;
}
```

Comment: It's a shame `$.` starts with 1

Comment: @mpapec: You can assing to it: `seek DATA, 0, 1; $. = -1; while (<DATA>) { ... }`.

Comment: Perhaps, but it raises too many [`wtf/minute`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hP33m.jpg) :)

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer this solution using `map`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cols = do {
  my @rows = map [ /[^:\s]+/g ], <DATA>;
  map [ map shift(@$_), @rows ], 0 .. $#{$rows[0]};
};

use Data::Dump;
dd \@cols;

__DATA__
col1a : col1b : col1c
col2a : col2b : col2c
col3a : col3b : col3c
```

**output**

```
[
  ["col1a", "col2a", "col3a"],
  ["col1b", "col2b", "col3b"],
  ["col1c", "col2c", "col3c"],
]
```

Comment: @jm666: My markup was missing a blank line before the code block, so the `use strict` and `use warnings` appeared as part of the preceding text.

Comment: Ahh soo.. I was read it as a recommendation to using the pragmas.. :)